# SUPEE 11086 patches for Magento Version 1.9.0.1 where can we get?

Tags: supee-11086

I don't see the latest security patch update SUPEE 11086 for Magento version 1.9.0.1. Will it not needed for the mentioned version?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention for the new patch has changed for some reason.

Now instead of having the range the patch applies to support e.g (1.9.0.1 - 1.9.2.6). It just has the max it applies to.

So for Magento 1.9.0.1 you need to apply the patch labeled as `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1.sh`

In the old naming conversion it would have been `PATCH_SUPEE-11086 CE for 1.7.0.2 - 1.9.1.0`